# T-SQL - Creating a Local User On Windows OS

Tags: windows, t-sql, local

My requirement is that I need to create a local user on my System (On my Windows OS) using T-SQL. And I need to set this user under ‘Administrators’ group.

Using this local user I should be able to login to my Windows OS (At System Startup).

Is it possible? If so may I know how could we do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [xp_cmdshell for T-SQL](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/xp_aa-sz.htm)

**Example**

> The rows are returned in an
>   `nvarchar(255)` column.
>
> Executing this xp_cmdshell statement
>   returns the following result set:

```
xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe', NO_OUTPUT
```

You should also look over the security when doing this, see this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175398(SQL.80).aspx)

**Adding users through command line**

See this documentation on [adduser](http://ss64.com/nt/addusers.html)

> Syntax
>
> Create Users:

```
        AddUsers /c filename [/s:x] [/?] Domain Password_options
```

> Dump to file:

```
        AddUsers /d{:u} filename [/s:x] [/?] Domain Password_options
```

> Erase Users:

```
        AddUsers /e filename [/s:x] [/?] Domain Password_options
```